# WinSCP - How to open file from command line in Windows

Tags: windows, winscp

How to open file from command line in Windows (the current connection)

examle: (10 = set position cursor line , filename = "/var/www/index.php" )

```
c:\winscp -10 "/var/www/index.php"
```

Thank you to help..

Comment: What does it mean *"open file from command line in Windows"*? Please explain. Though no matter what you mean, which actually does not look like a programming question. You should probably move this to [su].

Comment: :Maritn and how can I move?

Comment: Delete here, re-post there.